# JavaScript - HTML select element onchange trigger for already selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**GOAL:**
To load href value whenever somebody select option from the dropdown list - **even if that option is already selected**.

**PROBLEM:**
Although code bellow work, it doesn't work when some option is already selected (clicked). For example, lets say that i clicked on option "By price". New page will be loaded (fine), and option "By price" is selected by default and it is now on top of the list above the "By name" option.

Now i want to select again option "By price" **and now loading page will not work**.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="" class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_name">By name</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,mf_name">By MF</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_price">By price</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_special">By type</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are a binding to the `change` event which only triggers if you change a selection. Try `click`, `keyup`, `mouseup` or similar, or even a combination of them to cover a few possible ways to select a value.

Comment: Just tried that. It work, but just partially, because it doesnt even let me to select some other option. It is fired as soon as i click on dropdown, so its not good for my scenario.

Comment: goes against what users are familiar with since once an option is selected they know nothing happens when you try to clcik same option... sounds like a UI design problem. Add a `refresh` button

Comment: Not actually. Because there are arrows(up and down) added on the end of option text, and they change places according to selection. For the sake of simplicity i removed them from example.

Comment: replace select with clickable list perhaps

Comment: have to do something different... can't get events to fire on an already selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select').blur(function(){
    window.location = $('option:selected', this).val();
});
```

Blur will always be captured in the manner you desire.

[The working jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/NCS8z/)

Comment: worth a shot and good idea ... still not intuitive for users though...have to click somewhere else in page first...sure seems like a `refresh` button make more sense to me

Comment: I used this as starting point and I have added something like refresh button as charlietfl suggested. Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty option to your select box. If you want to select what is already selected, select this empty option first, then the one you want. That way it'll work.

```
<select name="" class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_name">By name</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,mf_name">By MF</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_price">By price</option>
    <option value="/index.php/by,product_special">By type</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make such a workflow, not only because its hard to maintain for all browsers, its hard for keyboard-accessibility (WCAG), so if you are binding it to "onchange" you are not bothering of keyboard-users pressing up and down when that thing has focus.

what if you bind it when loosing the focus (onblur)?

Answer (score 0):

- bind method to onfocus where you save selection and remove selection
- then onchange will always be triggered. there you can do whatever you want (even using the original saved selection)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading a new page anyway,
Reset the selected index

```
onchange="var val=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
this.selectedIndex=0;
window.top.location.href=val">
```